# Buck-boost with LT8705

Tags: buck-boost

I would like to do a buck-boost using H-bridge topology. I found the [LT8705](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/8705ff.pdf). I have two questions I don't understand.

1. How to choose the inductor of H-bridge buck-boost? The datasheet is using boost mode to calculate, but I don't know why.
2. How to use only one compensator to compensate all the modes? (Buck mode, boost mode, buck boost.)

Comment: It's not and H-bridge but a buck-boost converter. No application note for this one what I can find. Have you tried to simulate it in LTspice?

Comment: @winny NO, I want to do a simulation, but I don't know how to design the compensator in this topology, and I use simplis.

Comment: @winny yes no appliation note, so I am confused

Comment: I would start by calculating the worst case scenario for boost and buck in your application and choose the inductor according to peak current for the worst of the two and maximum inductance required for the worst of the two.

Comment: @winny I got it, and what about compensator

Comment: @Jitter456, did you read the section "Loop compensation" on page 33 of the datasheet?

Comment: @ThePhoton  Yes, I read it, but it seems like try and error.